# Conformal mapping onto lower half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

How to conformaly mapping region $$D = \{|z|>1,\Im z > 0\}$$ on lower half plane?
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The map $\frac{1}{z}$ brings $D$ to the part of the unit disk with negative imaginary part. Next, map this region to the full disk. Do you know any famous transformations that bring the unit disk to the upper half plane?

Comment: @Nicholas Roberts Mobius?